# Why are the videos on the most_recent standard feed so out of date?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I'm trying to grab the most recently uploaded videos.  There's a [standard feed](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Standard_feeds) for that - it's called `most_recent`.  I don't have any problems grabbing the feed, but when I look at the entries inside, they're all half a year old, which is hardly recent.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import requests
import os.path as P
import sys
from lxml import etree
import datetime

namespaces = {"a": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", "yt": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"}
fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z"

class VideoEntry:
    """Data holder for the video."""

    def __init__(self, node):
        self.entry_id = node.find("./a:id", namespaces=namespaces).text
        published = node.find("./a:published", namespaces=namespaces).text
        self.published = datetime.datetime.strptime(published, fmt)

    def __str__(self):
        return "VideoEntry[id='%s']" % self.entry_id

def paginate(xml):
    root = etree.fromstring(xml)
    next_page = root.find("./a:link[@rel='next']", namespaces=namespaces)
    if next_page == None:
        next_link = None
    else:
        next_link = next_page.get("href")
    entries = [VideoEntry(e) for e in root.xpath("/a:feed/a:entry", namespaces=namespaces)]
    return entries, next_link

prefix = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/"
standard_feeds = set("top_rated top_favorites most_shared most_popular most_recent most_discussed most_responded recently_featured on_the_web most_viewed".split(" "))
feed_name = sys.argv[1]
assert feed_name in standard_feeds
feed_url = prefix + feed_name
all_video_ids = []

while feed_url is not None:
    r = requests.get(feed_url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        break
    text = r.text.encode("utf-8")
    video_ids, feed_url = paginate(text)
    all_video_ids += video_ids

all_upload_times = [e.published for e in all_video_ids]
print min(all_upload_times), max(all_upload_times)
```

As you can see, it prints the min and max timestamps for the entire feed.

```
misha@misha-antec$ python get_standard_feed.py most_recent 
2013-02-02 14:40:02 2013-02-02 14:54:00 
misha@misha-antec$ python get_standard_feed.py top_rated 
2006-04-06 21:30:53 2013-07-28 22:22:38
```

I've glanced through the downloaded XML and it appears to match the output.  Am I doing something wrong?

Also, on an unrelated note, the feeds I'm getting are all about 100 entries (I'm paginating through them 25 at a time).  Is this normal?  I expected the feeds to be a bit bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the "Most-Recent-Feed"-Topic: There is a ticket for this one [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4113). Unfortunately, the YouTube-API-Teams doesn't respond or solved the problem so far.

Regarding the number of entries: That depends on the type of standardfeed, but for the most-recent-Feed it´s usually around 100.

*Note*: You could try using the "orderby=published" parameter to get recents videos, although I don´t know how "recent" they are.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?orderby=published&prettyprint=True
```

You can combine this query with the "category"-parameter or other ones (region-specific queries - like for the standard feeds - are not possible, afaik).